# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKCS11 KeyStore not available, Trying to Enable FIPS mode using SUNPKCS11 in java 11

Tags: java, fips, java-11, nss, sunpkcs11

I'm trying to enable FIPS mode using SUNPKCS11 with NSS in Java 11. I got this exception  **java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PKCS11 KeyStore not available.**

When I tried to enable FIPS in **Java 8** it works fine but doing the same in **Java 11** throws the exception.

The initialization of SUNPKCS11 changed from Java 8 to Java 11.

In Java 8:

```
  Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");      
  provider.configure(nssConfigFile);
```

Java 11:

```
  Provider provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(nssConfigFile);
  Security.addProvider(nssProvider);
```

After the initialization of SUNPKCS11 with config file, I'm trying to get the provider from the keystore as below.
One more thing is when I initialized the SUNPKCS11, it's **Provider.id.info** is set to
**Unconfigured and unusable PKCS11 provider** , Does this has some thing to do with?

```
KeyStore.getInstance("SUNPKCS11");
```

Then here I didn't have the PKCS11 in keystore.

My config file content look as below:

```
  name=nss-client   
  nssLibraryDirectory=X:\XXX\NSS\lib\   
  nssSecmodDirectory=X:\XXX\NSS\db\   
  nssModule=fips
```

Do I need to change something in the config file contents or is it a bug in Java 11?

Please help me with the valuable suggestions.

Comment: Did you take a look at [SunPKCS11 provider in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521791/sunpkcs11-provider-in-java-9) ?

Comment: yeah but i didn't get what you are trying to mention. Do I need to pass the config params and string rather than passing file or mention the slot id?

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I need to assign the return provider from configure method.

Answer (score 5):

Alright -- one of the comments on the original question contained the solution.  So, I'm re-documenting it here.

It appears that the `provider.configure(..)` method returns a *new* `Provider` rather than mutating the original `provider`.  With that in mind, you can do this instead:

```java
Provider oldProvider = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");
Provider newProvider = oldProvider.configure("yubihsm.conf");
Security.addProvider(newProvider);

// Hooray!  This works now!
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs11");
```

Comment: this works! thanks. for openjdk 9 above. this is imprtant.